# Error en C++ "[Error] 'else' without a previous 'if'"

Tags: c++, condiciones, else

Me sale un error común pero he verificado varias veces mi sintaxis y no encuentro el error, si alguien me pude corregir se lo agradecería error en c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
main(){
    char op;
    int n,slr;
    
    cout<<"bienvenido a tieda store\n";
    cout<<"seleccione su tipo de categoria\n";
    cout<<"area de caja     1";
    cout<<"bodega   2";
    cout<<"opcion   ";
    slr=1000000;
    
    switch(op=getche()){
        case'1':system ("cls");
                cout<<"AREA DE CAJA\n";
                cout<<"escoja su numero de caja\n";
                cout<<"caja     1";
                cout<<"caja     2";
                
        break;
                
                switch(op=getche()){
                    case '1' :system("cls");
                                cout<<"Caja para Clientes Preferenciales\n";
                                cout<<"su bonificacion por ventas dependera de las ventas hechas por las cajas durante el mes\n";
                                cout<<"digite ventas hechas durante el mes\n";
                                cin>>n;
                            
                                if(n>=2000000 && n<=10000000)
                                    cout<<n*90/100;
                                    cout<<"salario final\n";
                                    cout<<slr+n;
                                else
                                    if(n>10000000)
                                        cout<<n*80/100;
                                        cout<<"salario final\n";
                                        cout<<slr+n;
                    
                    break;
                    
                    case '2' :system("cls");
                                cout<<"Caja Para Personal Natural\n";
                                cout<<"su bonificacion dependera de las personas atendidas durante el mes\n";
                                cout<<"digite personas atendidas\n";
                                cin>>n;
                            
                                if(n>=50 && 100)
                                    cout<<n*90/100;
                                    cout<<"salario final\n";
                                    cout<<slr+n;
                                else
                                    if(n>100)
                                        cout<<n*80/100;
                                        cout<<"salario final\n";
                                        cout<<slr+n;
                                    
                        break;      
                }
        
        case '2' : system("cls");
                    cout<<"BODEGA\n";
                    cout<<"seleccine categoria de bloque\n";
                    cout<<"bloque   1";
                    cout<<"bloque   2";
                    
        break;
                    switch(op=getche()){
                        case '1' : system("cls");
                                    cout<<"BLOQUE DE MERCANCIA URGENTE\n";
                                    cout<<"su bonoficacin de pendera de la cantidad de mercancia almacenada\n";
                                    cout<<"digite la cantidad\n";
                                    cin>>n;
                                    
                                    if(n>=20 && n<=50)
                                        cout<<n*90/100;
                                        cout<<"salario final\n";
                                        cout<<slr+n;
                                    else
                                        if(n>50)
                                            cout<<n*20/100;
                                            cout<<"salario final\n";
                                            cout<<slr+n;
                        break;
                                    
                                    
                        case '2' : system("cls");
                                    cout<<"BLOQUE DE MERCANCIA POR DESPACHAR\n";
                                    cout<<"su salario final dependera de cantidad mercancia almacenada\n";
                                    cout<<"digite cantidad\n";
                                    cin>>n;
                                    
                                    if(n>=40 && n<=100)
                                        cout<<n*90/100;
                                        cout<<"salario final\n";
                                        cout<<slr+n;
                                    else
                                        if(n>100)
                                            cout<<n*20/100;
                                            cout<<"salario final\n";
                                            cout<<slr+n;
                        break;
                    }
                    
                
                    
                    
                    
    }
    
    
        
    system("pause>nul");    
}
```

He tenido problema al ejecutar el programa porque me sale un error común de:

> "[Error] 'else' without a previous 'if'"

He revisado los puntos y comas y no he encontrado donde estén, mal ya he mirado las librerías y todo correcto, pero no se que me falta, si alguien puede corregirme o guiarme donde queda el problema se los agradecería.

El código anterior citado es para un programa para calcular el salario final de un empleado, pero que esta en diferentes sectores de la empresa, se saca el sueldo final para los empleados de caja, pero este menu se divide en dos secciones, esta el menu de los de caja preferenciales y los de las caja para personas naturales, también se debe calcular el sueldo final para los empleados de  bodega que estos a su vez se dividen en la sección de mercancía por sacar urgente
y los de bodega que es por mercancía de bodega por guardar.

Comment: C++ no es como python. No basta con que el codigo este indentado para que el compilador sepa todo lo que va dentro del if. Si vas a poner mas de una instruccion, tiene que estar dentro de `{}`. (`if (condicion) {sentencia 1; sentencia 2; etc;}`)

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, a la función `main` le falta el tipo de retorno (`int`).

En segundo lugar, en C++ las instrucciones están delimitadas por `;` y se agrupan en bloques encerrados por llaves y la identación no le importa al compilador. Pero a nosotros sí, porque tener el código identado y una sola instrucción por línea lo hace más legible.

Por lo tanto, estos dos trozos de código son equivalentes:

```
// Forma 1
int a, b;
int suma = a + b;

// Forma 2
int a, b; int suma = a + b;
```

Todas las estructuras de control usan bloques de código. Así que necesitan estar rodeados por llaves. El único caso en el que puedes omitirlas es cuando tienes una sola instrucción en el bloque. Por ejemplo:

```
// Esto
if (edad > 18){
    printf("Ya eres mayor de edad");
} else {
    printf("Aún eres pequeño");
}

// Puedes escribirlo así

if (edad > 18)
    printf("Ya eres mayor de edad");
else
    printf("Aún eres pequeño");
```

Agregando las llaves que faltan, el código te queda así:

```
  #include <conio.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  using namespace std;

  int main() {
      char op;
      int n, slr;

      cout << "Bienvenido a tienda store\n";
      cout << "Seleccione su tipo de categoria\n";
      cout << "Area de caja     1";
      cout << "Bodega   2";
      cout << "Opción   ";
      slr = 1000000;

      switch (op = getche()) {
          case '1':
              system("cls");
              cout << "AREA DE CAJA\n";
              cout << "Escoja su numero de caja\n";
              cout << "Caja     1";
              cout << "Caja     2";

              switch (op = getche()) {
                  case '1':
                      system("cls");
                      cout << "Caja para Clientes Preferenciales\n";
                      cout << "Su bonificacion por ventas dependera de las "
                              "ventas hechas por las cajas durante el mes\n";
                      cout << "Digite ventas hechas durante el mes\n";
                      cin >> n;

                      if (n >= 2000000 && n <= 10000000) {
                          cout << n * 90 / 100;
                          cout << "Salario final\n";
                          cout << slr + n;
                      } else if (n > 10000000) {
                          cout << n * 80 / 100;
                          cout << "Salario final\n";
                          cout << slr + n;
                      }

                      break;

                  case '2':
                      system("cls");
                      cout << "Caja Para Personal Natural\n";
                      cout << "Su bonificacion dependera de las personas "
                              "atendidas durante el mes\n";
                      cout << "Digite personas atendidas\n";
                      cin >> n;

                      if (n >= 50 && n <= 100) {
                          cout << n * 90 / 100;
                          cout << "Salario final\n";
                          cout << slr + n;
                      } else if (n > 100) {
                          cout << n * 80 / 100;
                          cout << "Salario final\n";
                          cout << slr + n;
                      }

                      break;
              }
              break;

          case '2':
              system("cls");
              cout << "BODEGA\n";
              cout << "Seleccione categoria de bloque\n";
              cout << "Bloque   1";
              cout << "Bloque   2";

              switch (op = getche()) {
                  case '1':
                      system("cls");
                      cout << "BLOQUE DE MERCANCIA URGENTE\n";
                      cout << "Su bonoficacin de pendera de la cantidad de "
                              "mercancia almacenada\n";
                      cout << "Digite la cantidad\n";
                      cin >> n;

                      if (n >= 20 && n <= 50) {
                          cout << n * 90 / 100;
                          cout << "Salario final\n";
                          cout << slr + n;
                      } else if (n > 50) {
                          cout << n * 20 / 100;
                          cout << "Salario final\n";
                          cout << slr + n;
                      }
                      break;

                  case '2':
                      system("cls");
                      cout << "BLOQUE DE MERCANCIA POR DESPACHAR\n";
                      cout << "Su salario final dependera de cantidad mercancia "
                              "almacenada\n";
                      cout << "Digite cantidad\n";
                      cin >> n;

                      if (n >= 40 && n <= 100) {
                          cout << n * 90 / 100;
                          cout << "Salario final\n";
                          cout << slr + n;
                      } else if (n > 100) {
                          cout << n * 20 / 100;
                          cout << "Salario final\n";
                          cout << slr + n;
                      }
                      break;
              }
              break;
      }

      system("pause>nul");
  }
```

Por cierto, cuando copiaste y pegaste te dejaste unos `break` antes del resto del código así que esas instrucciones no llegarían a ejecutarse. Además que en un sitio escribiste `if (n >= 50 && 100)` en lugar de `if (n >= 50 && n <= 100)`. En este código está corregido.

---

Como podrás imaginar es un código muy largo y difícil de mantener. Algunas de las cosas que puedes hacer para que se entienda mejor son:

- `else if` permite introducir más condiciones en una serie de ifs conectados. Entonces puedes pasar de:

  ```
  else {
      if (...){
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

  A:

  ```
  else if (...) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Introducir funciones para algunas partes del código. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  int slr;

  void caja1();
  void caja2();
  void bloque1();
  void bloque2();

  void cajas() {
      char op;
      system("cls");
      cout << "AREA DE CAJA\n";
      cout << "Escoja su numero de caja\n";
      cout << "Caja     1";
      cout << "Caja     2";

      switch (op = getche()) {
          case '1':
              caja1();
              break;

          case '2':
              caja2();
              break;
      }
  }

  void bodegas() {
      char op;
      system("cls");
      cout << "BODEGA\n";
      cout << "Seleccione categoria de bloque\n";
      cout << "Bloque   1";
      cout << "Bloque   2";

      switch (op = getche()) {
          case '1':
              bloque1();
              break;

          case '2':
              bloque2();
              break;
      }
  }

  void caja1() {
      int n;
      system("cls");
      cout << "Caja para Clientes Preferenciales\n";
      cout << "Su bonificacion por ventas dependera de las ventas hechas por las cajas durante el mes\n";
      cout << "Digite ventas hechas durante el mes\n";
      cin >> n;

      if (n >= 2000000 && n <= 10000000) {
          cout << n * 90 / 100;
          cout << "Salario final\n";
          cout << slr + n;
      } else if (n > 10000000) {
          cout << n * 80 / 100;
          cout << "Salario final\n";
          cout << slr + n;
      }
  }

  void caja2() {
      int n;
      system("cls");

      cout << "Caja Para Personal Natural\n";
      cout << "Su bonificacion dependera de las personas atendidas durante el mes\n";
      cout << "Digite personas atendidas\n";
      cin >> n;

      if (n >= 50 && n <= 100) {
          cout << n * 90 / 100;
          cout << "Salario final\n";
          cout << slr + n;
      } else if (n > 100) {
          cout << n * 80 / 100;
          cout << "Salario final\n";
          cout << slr + n;
      }
  }

  void bloque1() {
      int n;
      system("cls");
      cout << "BLOQUE DE MERCANCIA URGENTE\n";
      cout << "Su bonoficacin de pendera de la cantidad de mercancia almacenada\n";
      cout << "Digite la cantidad\n";
      cin >> n;

      if (n >= 20 && n <= 50) {
          cout << n * 90 / 100;
          cout << "Salario final\n";
          cout << slr + n;
      } else if (n > 50) {
          cout << n * 20 / 100;
          cout << "Salario final\n";
          cout << slr + n;
      }
  }

  void bloque2() {
      system("cls");
      cout << "BLOQUE DE MERCANCIA POR DESPACHAR\n";
      cout << "Su salario final dependera de cantidad mercancia almacenada\n";
      cout << "Digite cantidad\n";
      cin >> n;

      if (n >= 40 && n <= 100) {
          cout << n * 90 / 100;
          cout << "Salario final\n";
          cout << slr + n;
      } else if (n > 100) {
          cout << n * 20 / 100;
          cout << "Salario final\n";
          cout << slr + n;
      }
  }

  int main() {
      char op;

      cout << "Bienvenido a tienda store\n";
      cout << "Seleccione su tipo de categoria\n";
      cout << "Area de caja     1";
      cout << "Bodega   2";
      cout << "Opción   ";
      slr = 1000000;

      switch (op = getche()) {
          case '1':
              cajas();
              break;
          case '2':
              bodegas();
              break;
      }

      system("pause>nul");
  }
  ```

  Por la similitud entre `cajas` y `bodegas` podrías incluso reescribir el código de manera en que puedas lograr el mismo resultado con una sola función. Al igual que `caja1`, `caja2`, `bloque1` y `bloque2`. Pero esa tarea te la dejo a tí.